# dojo require fails

Tags: dojo, dijit.tree

see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kcDz9/). This upon running gives an error in console. I'm currently on chrome. Is this a bug?

doing `require(["dijit/tree" ]` should load `.../digit/tree.js` but it gives a `404`

```
GET http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7.2/dijit//tree.js 404 (Not Found)
```

there should be only one `/`  but there are two!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to capitalize tree

```
require(["dijit/Tree"]
```

Comment: I'm accepting this because I meanwhile found an alternate way so didn't try this, I'm assuming it's correct